# On the cubic counterpart of Ramanujan's $\sqrt{\frac{\pi\,e}{2}} =1+\frac{1}{1\cdot3}+\frac{1}{1\cdot3\cdot5}+\frac{1}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7}+\dots$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, gamma-function, continued-fractions, error-function

We have Ramanujan's well-known,

$$\sqrt{\frac{\pi\,e}{2}}
=1+\frac{1}{1\cdot3}+\frac{1}{1\cdot3\cdot5}+\frac{1}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7}+\dots\color{blue}+\,\cfrac1{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{2}{1+\cfrac{3}{1+\ddots}}}}$$

However, as discussed in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4791520/4781), the series can also be expressed as a nice continued fraction. And since $\Gamma\big(\tfrac12\big) = \sqrt{\pi}$, we can then express the identity as,

$$\Gamma\big(\tfrac12\big)\sqrt{\frac{e}{2}} = 1+\cfrac{2/2}{2+\cfrac{3/2}{3+\cfrac{4/2}{4+\cfrac{5/2}{5+\ddots}}}} \; \color{blue}+ \; \cfrac1{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{2}{1+\cfrac{3}{1+\ddots}}}}$$

It turns out it may have a *cubic* counterpart,

$$\Gamma\big(\tfrac13\big)\sqrt[3]{\frac{e}{9}}
= 1+\cfrac{2/3}{2+\cfrac{3/3}{3+\cfrac{4/3}{4+\cfrac{5/3}{5+\ddots}}}} \; \color{blue}+ \; \cfrac1{1+\cfrac{2}{1+\cfrac{3}{1+\cfrac{\color{red}5}{1+\ddots}}}}$$

where the 4th continued fraction is missing numerators $P(n)=3n+1 = 4,7,10,13,\dots$ The four cfracs apparently have closed-forms as,

\begin{align}
\Gamma\big(\tfrac12\big)\sqrt{\frac{e}{2}} 
&= \sqrt{\frac{e}{2}}\times\Big(\Gamma\big(\tfrac12\big)-\Gamma\big(\tfrac12,\tfrac12\big)\Big)\; \color{blue}+ \, \sqrt{\frac{e}{2}}\times\Big(\Gamma\big(\tfrac12,\tfrac12\big)\Big)\\[6pt]
\Gamma\big(\tfrac13\big)\sqrt[3]{\frac{e}{9}} 
&= \sqrt[3]{\frac{e}{9}}\times\Big(\Gamma\big(\tfrac13\big)-\Gamma\big(\tfrac13,\tfrac13\big)\Big)\; \color{blue}+ \; \sqrt[3]{\frac{e}{9}}\times\Big(\Gamma\big(\tfrac13,\tfrac13\big)\Big)
\end{align}

and their decimal expansions are [A060196](https://oeis.org/A060196), [A108088](https://oeis.org/A108088), [A108744](https://oeis.org/A108744), [A108745](https://oeis.org/A108745), respectively.

---

**Questions**:

1. Given [Pochhammer symbol](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html) $(x)_n$, how do we prove that,

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n (\frac12)_n} 
&= \sqrt{\frac{e}{2}} \times\,\Gamma\big(\tfrac12\big)\,\operatorname{erf}\Big(\sqrt{\tfrac 12}\Big)\\ 
&= \sqrt{\frac{e}{2}}\times\Big(\Gamma\big(\tfrac12\big)-\Gamma\big(\tfrac12,\tfrac12\big)\Big) = 1+\cfrac{2/2}{2+\cfrac{3/2}{3+\cfrac{4/2}{4+\cfrac{5/2}{5+\ddots}}}}
\end{align}

2. Similarly, how do we show that,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^n (\frac13)_n} = \sqrt[3]{\frac{e}{9}}\times\Big(\Gamma\big(\tfrac13\big)-\Gamma\big(\tfrac13,\tfrac13\big)\Big) = 1+\cfrac{2/3}{2+\cfrac{3/3}{3+\cfrac{4/3}{4+\cfrac{5/3}{5+\ddots}}}}$$

**P.S.** Part of Question 1 has already been answered in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4327258/4781), but I included it for comparison and to see if an alternative or modified proof can be found that covers both Question 1 and 2.

Comment: Using one of my question we can express the roots of : $$1+x+x^2/2+x^3/6+\cdots+x^n/n!-e^{\sqrt{e\pi/2}}=0$$ using continued fraction and iteration .Are you interested ?

Comment: @ErikSatie That involves $\Gamma\big(\frac12\big)=\sqrt{\pi}$ which is already settled. Of more interest will be finding a "nicer" continued fraction for the case $\Gamma\big(\frac14\big)$ I gave in my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research, I managed to answer my own question and found the pieces of the puzzle scattered in various places. Recall that $\Gamma\big(\tfrac12\big) = \sqrt{\pi}$, so to recap,

$$\Gamma\big(\tfrac12\big)\sqrt{\frac{e}{2}}
=1+\frac{1}{1\cdot3}+\frac{1}{1\cdot3\cdot5}+\frac{1}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7}+\dots\color{blue}+\,\cfrac1{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{2}{1+\cfrac{3}{1+\ddots}}}}$$

$$\Gamma\big(\tfrac13\big)\sqrt[3]{\frac{e}{3^2}}
=1+\frac{1}{1\cdot4}+\frac{1}{1\cdot4\cdot7}+\frac{1}{1\cdot4\cdot7\cdot10}+\dots\color{blue}+ \; \cfrac1{1+\cfrac{2}{1+\cfrac{3}{1+\cfrac{\color{red}5}{1+\ddots}}}}$$

where the 2nd continued fraction is missing numerators $P(n)=3n+1 = 4,7,10,\dots,$ etc. It turns out Ramanujan's identity could be generalized not just for deg-$3$, but for ***all*** higher degrees as well. The secret was quite simple and depended on the identity,

$$\Gamma(a) = \gamma(a,x) \color{blue}+ \Gamma(a,x)$$

with *lower* $\gamma(a,x)$ and *upper* $\Gamma(a,x)$ [incomplete gamma functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html). Or as integrals,

$$\int_0^\infty t^{a-1}e^{-t}dt = \int_0^x t^{a-1}e^{-t}dt \; \color{blue}+ \int_x^\infty t^{a-1}e^{-t}dt$$

The trick then is to multiply each term by a fractional power of $e$ such that the addends can be expressed by a nice *series* or *continued fraction* or *both*. Let $a=x$, then the first addend becomes,

\begin{align}\frac{e^a}{a^{a-1}}\,\gamma(a,a)
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a^n}{(a)_n}\\[4pt]
&= {_1F_1}(1;a+1;a)\\[4pt]
&= 1+\cfrac{2a}{2+\cfrac{3a}{3+\cfrac{4a}{4+\cfrac{5a}{5+\ddots}}}}
\end{align}

The equivalence of the confluent hypergeometric function $_1F_1$ and the continued fraction was known to Ramanujan. The second addend becomes,

\begin{align}\frac{e^a}{a^{a-1}}\,\Gamma(a,a)
&= \cfrac{a}{1-\cfrac{1(1-a)}{3-\cfrac{2(2-a)}{5-\cfrac{3(3-a)}{7-\ddots}}}}
\end{align}

A [version](https://web.archive.org/web/20230326021917/https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/0017) of the second cfrac can also be found in his Notebooks and a general form is in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3952963/4781). However, note that Ramanujan used a *different* cfrac for $a = 1/2$, and the one for $a=1/3$ (not by Ramanujan) is also not from this family. And they do not seem to be in [Wolfram's list](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma2/10/). Thus, a few mysteries remain. For $a=1/4$, we get,

$$\Gamma\big(\tfrac14\big)\sqrt[4]{\frac{e}{4^3}}
=1+\frac{1}{1\cdot5}+\frac{1}{1\cdot5\cdot9}+\frac{1}{1\cdot5\cdot9\cdot13}+\dots\color{blue}+ \; \cfrac{1/4}{1-\cfrac{3/4}{3-\cfrac{14/4}{5-\cfrac{33/4}{7-\ddots}}}}$$

**P.S.** Can someone find a simpler cfrac for $a=1/4$, preferably similar to the the previous cases?

Answer (score 1):

You should be interested by :

$$\int_{0}^{∞}(((-1 + \sqrt{1 + 4 x^4})/(2 x^2) - 1) - ((-1 + \sqrt{1 + x^4})/x^2 - 1)) dx = -(\sqrt{2} - 2) Γ(3/4)^2)/\sqrt{π}≈0.496286$$

You can use reflection formula .

Nota bene: the CF in the integral are simple.